# I there any downtime in kubernetes upgrade?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am planning to upgrade the kubernetes version of AWS EKS from 1.15 to 1.16. I understood that there is no downtime while upgrading the cluster plane of the kubernetes. But I am not sure if there is a downtime while upgrading the worker nodes of the kubernetes.

Is there any downtime while upgrading the kubernetes version?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have deployed your workload on the cluster and how you are planning to upgrade the worker nodes. Note the following items

1. Drain each worker node one by one and upgrade each one by one.
2. Use deployment, statefulset, daemonset instead of bare pods directly.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/

Comment: I am using the cloudformation autoscaling group. I have assigned a pause time for it. But I am not sure how the pods get scheduled in new worker node.